# Does "On Error GoTo errorHandler:" remain active for the rest of the sub if it is not triggered?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

This Code tries to select a checkbox; if it does not exist it will create the checkbox via the errorHandler. I was wondering; if an error occurs later in this sub, will it still be directed to that errorHandler? In other words, will VBA attempt to create a checkbox anytime I have an error during this sub? Or does ErrorHandling only look at the next line that occurs after "On Error Goto ...:"

```
Sub PrepNewPurchaseEntryForm()
'no relevant VBA happens here   

Dim companyCount As Integer:  companyCount = colCount("CompanyUserEntries")
Call FocusOnSheet("NewPurchaseEntry")
For i = 3 To companyCount
    Dim companyName As String: companyName = Sheets("CompanyUserEntries").Cells(1, i).Value
    On Error GoTo Err1:
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(companyName)).Select
    ''if error occurs here, will Err1 still be called?
Next i
    ''if error occurs here, will Err1 still be called?
    Exit Sub

Err1:
    Call PlaceCheckBox(("B" & (i + 7)), companyName)
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Sorry this might seem like a stupid question but I have been reading up on ErrorHandling but i couldn't really find anything that explicitly explained this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`On Error GoTo xxxx` error handler will stay active as long as you you don't set another error handler or remove it with `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: You can look at [this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) to get more detailed informations on error handling.

Comment: Use `On Error Goto 0`.

Comment: There is no 'most compact/least arduous' way of doing that ;-) . Just use `On Error Goto 0` as soon as the error handler is not needed anymore to restore the default.

Comment: Yeah my bad, thanks very much, sorry I had removed my comment. already when i read this. I realized a little late. :/

Comment: Why does my Stupidity always arrive way sooner than my Common sense!?

Comment: Note that in your particular case, you might want to `Resume` instead of `Resume Next` at the end of you error handler, but it is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, I did realize that, but I was actually kinda using the .select line to see if it exists. I bet there's a better way of doing that though.